# How to create catalog price rule while initializing module?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules, rules, catalog-rules

I'm trying to create catalog rule by installing the module, but it's not working.
This is my CreateRule\Setup\**InstallData.php** file

```
<?php
namespace Perspective\CreateRule\Setup;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\CatalogRuleRepository
     */
    private $catalogRuleRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\CatalogRuleRepository $catalogRuleRepository
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->catalogRuleRepository = $catalogRuleRepository;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        
        $rule = $this->ruleFactory->create()
        ->setName('PriceDiscountCron Rule')
        ->setDescription('Rule from Price Discount Module')
        ->setIsActive(0) 
        ->setCustomerGroupIds(array(1))
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) 
        ->setFromDate('') 
        ->setToDate('') 
        ->setSimpleAction('by_percent') 
        ->setDiscountAmount(10) 
        ->setStopRulesProcessing(0);

        try {
            $this->catalogRuleRepository->save($rule);
        } catch (Exception $e) {                    
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

I found out new error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.

Create a new data patch PHP file in your module's.

file path:- **Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/CatalogPriceRule.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data;

use Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleInterfaceFactory; use Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory; use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface; use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

class CreateCatalogPriceRule implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface {
    /**
     * @var RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * @var RuleInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $ruleDataFactory;

    public function __construct(
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        RuleInterfaceFactory $ruleDataFactory
    ) {
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->ruleDataFactory = $ruleDataFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $ruleData = [
            'name' => 'New Catalog Price Rule',
            'description' => 'Description of the new catalog price rule',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'website_ids' => [1],
            'customer_group_ids' => [1],
            'from_date' => '2023-05-15',
            'to_date' => '2023-05-31',
            'simple_action' => 'by_percent',
            'discount_amount' => 10,        ];

        $rule = $this->ruleFactory->create();

        $ruleDataObject = $this->ruleDataFactory->create(['data' => $ruleData]);        $rule->setData($ruleDataObject->getData());         $rule->save();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        // code to revert the changes made in apply()
    }  }
```

please run this command:- **php bin/magento s:up**

Comment: Now i have this problem
Unable to apply data patch Perspective\CreateRule\Setup\Patch\Data\CreateRule for module Perspective_CreateRule. Original exception message: Area code is not set

Comment: Upd: I solved this by adding $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml'); to apply function, where $this->appState is \Magento\Framework\App\State class